# How can I change text file encoding format as unicode by using XSLT?

Tags: xslt, unicode, encoding, xslt-1.0

Can any one help me out to change encoding format of the text to unicode? I need to be view arabic characters, right now I am using windows-1256 encoding even though in my text file I could Question marks characters where I need unicode format, how can achieve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output media-type="text/xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding ="windows-1256"/>
```

output required in **Unicode** format

Answer (score 0):

Set the encoding attribute of xsl:output to whatever you require.

Note, there is no such thing as "unicode format". There are many characters sets within the unicode database. A character set is not the same thing as an encoding. There are many encodings that unicode strings can be encoded into.

Possibly you want to output in either UTF-8 or UTF-16LE. Both of these are encodings. Windows-1256 is also a unicode encoding, but it is not a "Universal" one. A Universal encoding is one where there is a one-to-one mapping of Unicode code points in the unicode database to the value-space of the encoding.

Comment: `encoding` is an attribute of `xsl:output` -- not of `xsl:stylesheet`.